# documentation about the file format of spark rdd.saveAsObjectFile

Tags: apache-spark

Spark can save a rdd to a file with `rdd.saveAsObjectFile("file")`.
I need to read this file outside Spark. According to [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization), using the default spark serializer, this file is just a sequence of objects serialized with the standard Java serialization. However, I guess the file has a header and a separator between objects. I need to read this file, and use [jdeserialize](https://github.com/unsynchronized/jdeserialize) to deserialize each Java/Scala object (as I don't have the class definition).

Where can I find the documentation about the file format produced by `rdd.saveAsObjectFile("file")` (with the standard serializer, not Kryo serializer)?

---

**Update**
Working example based on VladoDemcak answer:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._

def deserialize(data: Array[Byte]) =
  new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)).readObject()

val path = new Path("/tmp/part-00000")
val config = new Configuration()
val reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(FileSystem.get(new Configuration()), path, config)
val key = NullWritable.get
val value = new BytesWritable

while (reader.next(key, value)) {
  println("key: {} and value: {}.", key, value.getBytes)
  println(deserialize(value.getBytes()))
}
reader.close()
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dportabella/dd8886ebb8d5f0eddd1196e1c30e34f6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very interesting question so I will try to explain what I know about this staff. You can check [`saveAsObjectFile`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/02f203107b8eda1f1576e36c4f12b0e3bc5e910e/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1494) and only documentation I saw about some details [is API javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@saveAsObjectFile(path:String):Unit)

```
  /**
   * Save this RDD as a SequenceFile of serialized objects.
   */
  def saveAsObjectFile(path: String): Unit = withScope {
    this.mapPartitions(iter => iter.grouped(10).map(_.toArray))
      .map(x => (NullWritable.get(), new BytesWritable(Utils.serialize(x))))
      .saveAsSequenceFile(path)
  }
```

so as I know `saveAsObjectFile` produces [`SequenceFile`](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile). And based on documentation for sequenceFile it has header with `version`, `classname`, `metadata` ...

> There are 3 different SequenceFile formats:
>
> Uncompressed key/value records.  Record compressed key/value records -
>   only 'values' are compressed here.  Block compressed key/value records
>   - both keys and values are collected in 'blocks' separately and compressed. The size of the 'block' is configurable.
>
> all of the above formats share a common header (which is used by the
>   SequenceFile.Reader to return the appropriate key/value pairs).

For reading sequencefile we can use hadoop [SequenceFile.Reader](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html) implementation.

```
Path path = new Path("/hdfs/file/path/seqfile");
SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(FileSystem.get(new Configuration()), path, config);
WritableComparable key = (WritableComparable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
Writable value = (Writable) reader.getValueClass().newInstance();

while (reader.next(key, value)){
     logger.info("key: {} and value: {}.", key, value.getBytes());
     // (MyObject) deserialize(value.getBytes());
}

reader.close();
```

I have not tested this but based on [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) link you noticed in your question:

> By default, Spark serializes objects using Java’s ObjectOutputStream
>   framework

so in loop you can get bytes for value and deserialize with `ObjectInputStream`

```
public static Object deserialize(byte[] data){
    return new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)).readObject();
}
```

in your case you need to use your library (jdeserialize) in deserialize method - i guess `run(InputStream is, boolean shouldConnect)` etc.

Comment: i get a runtime error on when i call `reader.getKeyClass().newInstance()`, see my question updated. any idea?

Comment: it works; i've updated the question with the code. thanks!